# How to debug an invalid ParseKit Grammar?

Tags: objective-c, grammar, parsekit

I am trying to write a grammar for ParseKit so that it matches basic propositional logic sentences in an iphone app. Can someone please tell me where im going wrong.

```
@start = wff;
wff = disjunction (implies disjunction)?;
disjunction = conjuction (or conjuction)*;
conjunction = notExpression (and notExpression)*;
notExpression = (not | not primaryExpression);
primaryExpression = variable | lbracket wff rbracket;
variable = p | q | r;

p = 'P';
q = 'Q';
r = 'R';

implies = '→';
and = '∧';
or = '∨';
not = '¬';
lbracket = '(';
rbracket = ')';
```

Also how would i go about adding some extra call backs so that I can create a parse tree from the grammar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

I see one obvious problem: `conjunction` is misspelled in a couple of places in your grammar.

---

ParseKit's Grammar Parser's error messages are not the greatest. Ideally, you would receive a nice error message leading you to the problem (but, hey it's open source so anyone is welcome to contribute a fix of this nature).

However, I can tell you how I find these issues:

1. Update your ParseKit working copy to head of the [google code](https://code.google.com/p/parsekit/) trunk.
2. In Xcode, turn on breakpoints and add a breakpoint for all exceptions
3. Place your ParseKit grammar in this file: `~/Desktop/grammar.txt`
4. (Optional) Place any example input in this file: `~/Desktop/input.txt`
5. Run the ParseKit `DebugApp` target in Debug configuration.
6. Click the big `Run` button in the window that appears when the app runs.
7. Wait for an exception to be thrown. Breakpoint is hit.

If there is a bug in your grammar, you will find the exception has most likely occurred in a ParseKit Assembler callback like:

```
- (void)parser:(PKParser *)p didMatchExpression:(PKAssembly *)a
```

print `a` to the debug console. You'll see something like:

```
(lldb) po a
(PKAssembly *) $1 = 0x00000001075a9010 [] /conjuction/ ^(/or/ /conjuction/)/*
```

This is a printout of the `PKAssembly` object passed into your callback. Here you can see where ParseKit's grammar parser failed to parse your grammar. It appears that the ParseKit Grammar Parser failed while parsing this expression:

```
conjuction (or conjuction)*;
```

And from the position of the `^` (caret), you can tell the parser choked right after seeing the first `conjuction`.

This expression is located in just one line in your grammar:

```
disjunction = conjuction (or conjuction)*;
```

That's how I noticed that there was a misspelling in this line.

This approach will invariably lead you to the problematic line in your grammar. Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I couldnt get the debug app to run as I cant seem to get the code to run in netbeans. I am still pritty new to objective-c and xcode in general. The only way I managed to get the parsekit framework working was by using cocoapods.