# ParseKit - SQLite parser going into infinite recursion

Tags: objective-c, sql, sqlite, parsekit

For my application, I am trying to build an [SQLite](https://sqlite.org/) parser. As my application is using Objective-C, [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com/) seems like a good option. I read SQLite's [syntax diagrams](https://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html) and built a grammar based on them. However, when I try to parse something using this grammar, the parser goes into infinite recursion.

The only statements I need are SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE (I need SELECT mostly because the others refer to it). My @start is designed to handle multiple statements separated by semicolons:

```
@start = statement (';' statement)*;

statement = select_stmt | insert_stmt | update_stmt | delete_stmt ;
```

The statements are as follows:

```
select_stmt = select_core ( compound_operator select_core )* order_expr? limit_expr? ;
select_core = 'select' ( 'distinct' | 'all' )? result_column ( ',' result_column )* from_expr where_expr group_expr ;
result_column = '*' | table_name '.' '*' | expr ( 'as'? column_alias )? ;

insert_stmt = 'insert' or_on_failure? 'into' table_name insert_expr ;
insert_expr = insert_expr_cols? (insert_expr_values | select_stmt) ;
insert_expr_cols = '(' column_name ( ',' column_name )* ')' ;
insert_expr_values = 'values' '(' expr ( ',' expr )* ')' ;
insert_expr_defaults = 'default' 'values' ;

update_stmt = 'update' or_on_failure? qualified_table_name update_expr where_expr? limited_expr? ;
update_expr = 'set' update_expr_col ( ',' update_expr_col )* ;
update_expr_col = column_name '=' expr ;

delete_stmt = 'delete' 'from' qualified_table_name where_expr? limited_expr? ;
```

And their supporting expressions:

```
order_expr = 'order' 'by' ordering_term (',' ordering_term)* ;
limit_expr = 'limit' expr ( ( 'offset' | ',' ) expr )? ;
from_expr = 'from' join_source ;
where_expr = 'where' expr ;
group_expr = 'group' 'by' expr ( ',' expr )? ( 'having' expr )? ;

join_source = single_source ( join_operator single_source join_constraint? )* ;
single_source = table_name 'as' table_alias indexed_by? | '(' select_stmt ')' ( 'as'? table_alias )? | '(' join_source ')' ;

or_on_failure = 'or' on_failure ;
on_failure = 'rollback' | 'abort' | 'replace' | 'fail' | 'ignore' ;
limited_expr = order_expr limit_expr ;
```

Names, aliases:

```
database_name = name ;
table_name = (database_name '.')? name ;
column_name = (table_name '.')? name ;

table_alias = name ;
column_alias = name ;

index_name = name ;

type_name = name+ ( '(' number (',' number)? ')' )? ;
function_name = name ;
collation_name = name ;

qualified_table_name = table_name indexed_by? ;
```

Miscellaneous operators, etc:

```
indexed_by = 'indexed' 'by' index_name | 'not' 'indexed' ;

unary_operator = symbol ;
binary_operator = symbol ;
compound_operator = 'union' 'all'? | 'intersect' | 'except' ;
join_operator = ',' | 'natural'? ( 'left' 'outer'? | 'inner' | 'cross' ) 'join' ;

join_constraint = 'on' expr | 'using' '(' column_name ( ',' column_name )* ')' ;
```

Basic types:

```
literal = number
    | string
    | 'null'
    | 'current_time'
    | 'current_data'
    | 'current_timestamp' ;
number = Number ;
string = Word
    | QuotedString ;
name = Word
    | QuotedString ;
symbol = Symbol;
```

And the EXPR:

```
expr = literal
    | column_name
    | unary_operator expr
    | expr binary_operator expr
    | function_name '(' ( '*' | 'distinct'? expr ( ',' expr )* )? ')'
    | '(' expr ')'
    | 'cast' '(' expr 'as' type_name ')'
    | expr 'collate' collation_name
    | expr 'not'? ( 'like' | 'glob' | 'regexp' | 'match' ) expr ( 'escape' expr )?
    | expr ( 'isnull' | 'notnull' | 'not' 'null' )
    | expr 'is' 'not'? expr
    | expr 'not'? 'between' expr 'and' expr
    | expr 'not'? 'in' ( table_name | '(' ( select_stmt | expr ( ',' expr )* )? ')' )
    | ( 'not'? 'exists' )? '(' select_stmt ')'
    | 'case' expr? ( 'when' expr 'then' expr )+ ( 'else' expr )? 'end' ;
```

When I stepped through the code, the basic path was @start -> statement -> select_stmt -> select_core -> result_column -> expr -> expr -> expr...

After about 8-9k calls between PKParser's matchAndAssemble: and PKParser/Subclass's allMatchesFor:, something dies, usually from a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error (and then LLDB can't do anything either).

P.S.: If you're going to post an answer saying, 'Oh, you should really do/use *this*,' A) I like Objective-C. Don't tell me not to use it. It's my choice. My response will likely be a rant. And B) I tried digging through SQLite's source to use their parser. I never got anywhere. If you think I should use that, kindly post the source for their parser as a single file with no other dependencies.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

First, see my previous answers on [debugging ParseKit grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13637577/how-to-debug-an-invalid-parsekit-grammar) and [battling infinite recursion in ParseKit grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13866165/when-parsekit-tries-to-recognize-my-grammar-it-enters-an-infinite-loop-whats).

---

I think there might be an issue in the very first line (but I'm not a SQL expert, so I'm not sure). Shouldn't that be:

```
@start = (statement ';')+;
```

---

I would strongly recommend using camel case instead of underscores, as underscores will make your Objective-C callbacks very awkward and ugly. That is why camel case is the convention in ParseKit grammars.

---

However, I see the main issue. Your grammar includes **Left Recursion** which is not allowed in ParseKit grammars. Particularly in your `expr` prodcution (I haven't looked closely to see if it is elsewhere too).

ParseKit is fine with recursion, but **not left recusion**. The best explanation of this is in  [Steven Metsker's "Building Parsers with Java"](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201719622). Or [search the web](http://web.cs.wpi.edu/~kal/PLT/PLT4.1.2.html).

But basically left recursion is when a production immediately references itself (on the left side of an expression):

```
e = e '-' Number;
```

or

```
e = Number | e '-' Number;
```

Instead, you must design your grammars to remove left recursion like:

```
e = Number ('-' Number)*;
```