# BNF Grammar for units of measurement

Tags: objective-c, grammar, units-of-measurement, bnf, parsekit

I'm using [ParseKit](https://github.com/itod/parsekit) to parse units of measure. In order to do this I have to supply a grammar. I tried googling but that didn't get me far. While it is a fun exercise on my own I want to make sure I get it right. ParseKit is expecting a BNF Grammar like this:

```
@start  = number units;
units = unit+ | unit+ / unit+;
unit = prefix baseUnit | baseUnit;
prefix = '' | 'milli' | 'micro' | 'pico';
baseUnit = 'm' | 'meter' | 'g' | 'gram'
```

I'm looking to support input like:

```
25 m²
25 m^-3
25 m**-5/kg**-2
25 m/s squared
25 mm² per second
25 m/s
5 kg meters per second squared
3 m-kg/s^2
3 m kilograms
```

Comment: Are you looking for help improving your posted grammar so it fully supports your desired input?

Comment: @rmaddy well it would be nice to have a reference to an official/unofficial grammar but improvements are welcome.

Comment: What is `me`?  What is `kge`?

Comment: Your grammar doesn't support 'seconds' or 's', but your desired code does.  Your prefixes do not include 'kilo' for 'kg' (and 'kg' is anomalous in being the base unit of mass, instead of 'g'.  You don't have electrical units in the mix (not a big problem as I see it; you don't have any electrical examples).  You don't have abbreviations for the prefixes.  You're likely to find that 'mm' causes problems (is that metre-milli, a milli-milli, a metre-metre, or a millimetre).  You don't have support for plurals (meters, kilograms).

Comment: @robmayoff: I think it's like that the 'e' is for exponent, and is an alternative to '^' etc.  I puzzled a bit about that; is there an SI unit with abbreviation 'e'?  I don't think it is a significant problem, but there is a good deal of ambiguity lurking around.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you are correct. I'm removing from the example because after thinking about it it doesn't make much sense given we are talking about dimensions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Developer of [ParseKit](http://parsekit.com) here.

I have not looked closely at your example input to determine whether your grammar is semantically correct.

However, I *do* see two significant syntactical problems with your existing grammar.

---

First, this line contains Left Recursion (and also a syntax error with the unquoted `/`):

```
units = unit+ | unit+ / unit+;  // Incorrect. Will not work.
```

You must change this line to remove the Left Recursion to something like this:

```
units = unit ('/' unit)*;
```

See [my prior answer for more information on eliminating Left Recursion in your ParseKit grammars](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14597848/34934).

---

Second, I believe this line is attempting to allow an "empty" match by using `''`:

```
prefix = '' | 'milli' | 'micro' | 'pico';   // Incorrect. Will not work.
```

That is not supported syntax in ParseKit grammars. This feature is fully supported but the syntax is `Empty`, like:

```
prefix = Empty | 'milli' | 'micro' | 'pico';
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent. That clears a few things up. Finally I can parse something like 'pico grams' but not 'picograms'. I didn't see anything in the docs about how to parse substrings.

Comment: I guess I need to Customize PKTokenizer but I not sure where to start.

Comment: You can start by marking my answer here correct (or at least upvoting) and then asking a new question about tokenizing :). I answer all questions tagged `ParseKit` here in a timely manner.

Answer (score 1):

[This grammar](http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/udunits/udunits-2/udunits2lib.html#Grammar) I found on unidata.ucar.edu looks pretty official though unwieldily and doesn't contain the prefixes or units.

Unit-Spec: one of
             nothing
             Shift-Spec

```
 Shift-Spec: one of
         Product-Spec
         Product-Spec SHIFT REAL
         Product-Spec SHIFT INT
         Product-Spec SHIFT Timestamp

 Product-Spec: one of
         Power-Spec
         Product-Spec Power-Spec
         Product-Spec MULTIPLY Power-Spec
         Product-Spec DIVIDE Power-Spec

 Power-Spec: one of
         Basic-Spec
         Basic-Spec INT
         Basic-Spec EXPONENT
         Basic-Spec RAISE INT

 Basic-Spec: one of
         ID
         "(" Shift-Spec ")"
         LOGREF Product_Spec ")"
         Number

 Number: one of
         INT
         REAL

 Timestamp: one of
         DATE
         DATE CLOCK
         DATE CLOCK CLOCK
         DATE CLOCK INT
         DATE CLOCK ID
         TIMESTAMP
         TIMESTAMP INT
         TIMESTAMP ID

 SHIFT:
         <space>* <shift_op> <space>*

 <shift_op>: one of
         "@"
         "after"
         "from"
         "since"
         "ref"

 REAL:
         the usual floating-point format

 INT:
         the usual integer format

 MULTIPLY: one of
         "-"
         "."
         "*"
         <space>+
         <centered middot>

 DIVIDE:
         <space>* <divide_op> <space>*

 <divide_op>: one of
         per
         PER
         "/"

 EXPONENT:
         ISO-8859-9 or UTF-8 encoded exponent characters

 RAISE: one of
         "^"
         "**"

 ID: one of
         <id>
         "%"
         "'"
         "\""
         degree sign
         greek mu character

 <id>:
         <alpha> <alphanum>*

 <alpha>:
         [A-Za-z_]
         ISO-8859-1 alphabetic characters
         non-breaking space

 <alphanum>: one of
         <alpha>
         <digit>

 <digit>:
         [0-9]

 LOGREF:
         <log> <space>* <logref>

 <log>: one of
         "log"
         "lg"
         "ln"
         "lb"

 <logref>:
         "(" <space>* <re> ":"? <space>*

 DATE:
         <year> "-" <month> ("-" <day>)?

 <year>:
         [+-]?[0-9]{1,4}

 <month>:
         "0"?[1-9]|1[0-2]

 <day>:
         "0"?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|"30"|"31"

 CLOCK:
         <hour> ":" <minute> (":" <second>)?

 TIMSTAMP:
         <year> (<month> <day>?)? "T" <hour> (<minute> <second>?)?

 <hour>:
         [+-]?[0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]

 <minute>:
         [0-5]?[0-9]

 <second>:
         (<minute>|60) (\.[0-9]*)?
```